# is splitting a question a good practice?

Tags: support

Say, my question [unary minus for 0x80000000 (signed and unsigned)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474699/unary-minus-for-0x80000000-signed-and-unsigned) is really a 4 questions:

- unary minus for signed 0x80000000 in c++
- unary minus for signed 0x80000000 in c
- unary minus for unsigned 0x80000000 in c++
- unary minus for unsigned 0x80000000 in c

My merging all of them into one question seems to create misunderstanding. More, there are no possibility to choose the best answer, because different persons answer to different parts of my question!

Still, asking all the 4 of them as distinct questions may be considered as flooding. What is the better way to do?

UPDATE1: it seems to me, that such a merged question is good practice on discussion forum; but on SO I need to ask all of them as distinct questions, need I?

UPDATE2: Or may be SO will introduce special feature "multipart question" to allow to answer to different parts of a question and to choose the best answer to **each** of the different parts of a question?

Comment: Why exactly do you need to ask multi that you can't extrapolate from one of those?

Comment: @random IFAIK c and c++ at least have different wording (you can look at standards), and have different rules for signed and unsigned. Yes, there is a posibility of The Greatest Answer That Will Answer All The 4 Cases, but still it is not the case. Yes, I can wait for some time and reask my 4 questions later, say, after some days.

Comment: @random BTW, it seems that my question will often be multipart. There are also a different kind of multipart-ness: that is, a second part (and third part) of my question may highly depend on the first part. That multipart question may be rare on stackoverflow.com, but may be suitable for programmers.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @random To be precise, there are only 3 interesting questions, because answer to "unary minus for unsigned 0x80000000 in c++" is evident from c++ standard (I cited that part of c++ standard in my question).

Comment: With regard to your second update, I don't really think introducing a new feature is justified. There's a pretty high complexity cost with very little benefit. Just ask two different questions. The only way they need to be connected is that they'll both be listed under your account profile as questions you asked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say it should be **two** questions:

- unary minus for signed 0x80000000 in c++
- unary minus for unsigned 0x80000000 in c++

and then

- unary minus for unsigned 0x80000000 in c
- unary minus for signed 0x80000000 in c

Asking for the result of the unary minus operator applied to signed and unsigned `0x80000000` in one language seems like a natural, self-contained question to me.

Comment: Your approach seams reasonable. I shall use it with slight modification.

Comment: @user Just to clarify, the point is that C and C++ are different languages, and you should treat them as such in your questions just as if you were asking about Python and Java. Any time you're asking things that will have different answers, they should be different questions. The worst that will happen is 5 people will agree it's a duplicate and vote to close it. No big deal.